# Git weird deletion issue on Windows

Tags: windows, linux, git

The most of the work done in project was done on Linux platform, but now I'm trying to setup a clone on Windows platform.

The problem is that upon `git clone` a file `foo.bar` appears to be immediately deleted (and marked so in uncommited changes).

Checking `git ls-files` shows that file `foo.bar` is present in index.

I did some research and noticed the following chronology:

**Commit# .... Status**

100  .... Current HEAD

45 .... foo.bar modified (by me)

44 .... foo.bar deleted (by rookie teammate who never saw git before)

25 .... foo.bar modified (by me)

24 .... foo.bar created (by me)

I currently have no idea what I was doing to restore the file in commit #44. But I guess I did `git checkout commit43 -- foo.bar`, I might have done something else somewhere else, but I have no idea what really happened.

Currently the repository on Windows platform will not let me checkout the file `foo.bar`. Deleting repository and re-cloning results in the state I mentioned above.

On Linux platforms however, clone works 'perfectly' i.e. the file is there.

Please help me understand what went wrong and how to fix this.

**EDIT:**

For the record. The original filename is called `aux.py` and its a Windows issue.

Comment: It could be caused by having 2 different EOL (end of line formats) formats. I know there are documented issues with git and mixed EOL formats. Sorry I couldn't be more specific, but I've only read about and don't have first hand experience. Maybe it will point you in the right direction though. Good Luck.

Comment: What is the real name of the file? Maybe it's [not windows compatible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa365247), such as `AUX` or `NUL`.

Comment: the real filename is aux.py, please provide an anwer so I can give you the correct solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create files named `aux.*` on windows. The easiest solution is to rename the file and clone the repository again.